Web App (Linux) - BadGateway/Forbidden - The subscription is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm
I am having trouble creating a new Web App (Linux) for my client. My client owns the Microsoft/Azure tenant, and my account has been added as a co-administrator.
I have been able to create Azure Function apps, and also a PostgreSQL Flexible server for this client. But I have not been able to create an App Service - Web App (Linux) yet, because I keep getting an error that reads "BadGateway": Forbidden. The subscription '********************' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm.
Configuration for the web app:

Name: (was available)
Publish: Code
Runtime stack: .NET 8 (LTS)
Operating System: Linux
Region: mostly West US, but I tried a whole bunch (see below)
Linux Plan: (New)
Pricing Plan: Basic B1
Zone redundancy: Disabled
All other tabs were left at their defaults

Some things I have tried so far:

Double checking the billing account: credit card is loaded and we are on a Pay as you Go plan.
Deploying to different regions: I have tried every region in the USA. Also tried Central Canada. No luck.
Having my client use their Microsoft 365 admin account to deploy the web app: they got the same error.
Deploying using a different Resource Group: no luck
Re-registering the Microsoft.Web resource provider with my subscription: no luck
Disabling application insights: no luck

I am out of ideas--any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)
Screenshot of "Subscriptions" table.


Check in Subscriptions that the one you're trying to create it in doesn't have the status of suspended or disabled.

Thanks, I just provided a screenshot of the "Subscriptions" table. Looks like it's active though.

This is a known issue, and is likely due to a backend delay enabling the Microsoft.Web resource provider.
You'll need to wait up to 24 hours and try again.
If the issue persists then open a support request with Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1657059/the-subscription-is-not-allowed-to-create-or-updat

You were correct. I had to open a support ticket for them to adjust my subscription's reputation score.

How can you open a support ticket? im trying to do that, but i cant find the right option to do it.

I had a similar issue. I disabled my Subscription, created a new one and used that for Azure Functions.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
